# Connection Reset using Java's FileUtils or BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, file, download, lucee

we are having problems downloading a file from a remote server. We have a very high chance of getting a connection reset exception, although the same code works fine with other files we download from different servers.

We already tried using BufferedInputStream, but had the same problem there. That's why we switched to FileUtils copyURLToFile() method in hope that this will be a bit more robust. But that didn't improve the problem.

It seems like browsers don't have a problem downloading the file (at least it worked every time we tried), we just have the problem in Java (or Lucee using Java to be precise). Lucee's (and Railo's before that) built in functions had the same problem, that's why we started using Java in the first place. So far with no success.

Are there any ways to make this download more robust?

We also have little to no influence on the server that hosts the file, so ideally we should fix the problem on our side.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is at the server and must be investigated there.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that the problem happens only with one particular file ? If yes, is that file significantly bigger than the ones with which the problem does not occur ?

Comment: Which web server are you using in front of Lucee?

Comment: File Size: Yes, it's one of the bigger files (currently about 22MB and growing), but we also have one that's 200MB from another server, that works fine. And we are using NGINX currently, but we already had the problem with Apache before that.

Comment: _but we also have one that's 200MB from another server_ - The key to your comment is that the larger file is from _another server_. The `connection reset` error comes from the host server, not your server. Something will need to be done on that server as @EJP pointed out in his comment. That is why you continue to see the issue no matter what changes you make on your side.